# With scala play, how to convert a class that has an ObjectId to Json?

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework

I've got a case class:

```
case class Branch(
_id: ObjectId,
rootcommit: Option[ObjectId],
name: String,
commits: List[ObjectId]
)
```

I'd like to convert it to json after a

```
implicit val format = Json.format[Branch]
```

but i get this error

```
No implicit format for org.mongodb.scala.bson.ObjectId
```

and

```
implicit val format = Json.format[ObjectId]
```

does lead to

```
No unapply function found
[error]   implicit val format = Json.format[ObjectId]
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to define explicitly the format with :

```
implicit val objectIdFormat: Format[ObjectId] = Format(
    Reads[ObjectId] {
      case s: JsString => if (ObjectId.isValid(s.toString)) JsSuccess(new ObjectId(s.toString)) else JsError()
      case _           => JsError()
    },
    Writes[ObjectId]((o: ObjectId) => JsString(o.toHexString))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a companion object for your case class and putting the `Json.format` in that:

```
case class Branch(
                   _id: ObjectId,
                   rootcommit: Option[ObjectId],
                   name: String,
                   commits: List[ObjectId]
                 )

object Branch {
  implicit val format: OFormat[Branch] = Json.format[Branch]
}
```

Then you'd parse the Json with something like:

```
...
thing =>
  Json.parse(thing).as[Branch]
...
```

... or whatever suits your user need.